# changing a link inside javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a question about changing the link in an anchor tag from inside a function. The first 2 bits of code work, but the last one does not. Why is this?

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('myAnchor').href = "http://www.newgrounds.com";

var anchor = document.getElementById('myAnchor');
anchor.href = "http://www.newgrounds.com";

var anchor = document.getElementById('myAnchor').href;
anchor = "http://www.newgrounds.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the `anchor` variable in your code is a `string` and you refer it as if it was a pointer.

Here is your problem:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('myAnchor').href = "http://www.newgrounds.com";
```

Answer (score 1):

The last `anchor` points to a String, not to the actual Node. The first two are pointing to the Node.

```
#1

"http://www.newgrounds.com"
    ├── assigning to ───── document.getElementById('myAnchor').href
    └── assigning to ───── anchor

#2 anchor ---------------> HTMLAnchorElement        (Object)

#3 anchor ---------------> "http://www.example.com" (String)
```

Comment: @AmitJoki: what do you mean? You've obviously got to type it, look at the markdown.

Comment: @AmitJoki - You can click on `edit` to see what I have entered.

Comment: @OneKitten, I just appreciated his arrow diagrams.

Comment: @AmitJoki - I'm using [Cangjie IME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cangjie_input_method) and it lets me enter those lines very easily: http://imgur.com/K2rEUZ7 :)

Comment: Thank you I actually figured this out completely thanks to you. Heck of a brainteaser when your just learning ;p

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are only editing the value of the variable which is a string, you haven't set it to the element yet. You will have to use a pointer for that

Answer (score 0):

Because in the before to last line, anchor contains the actual `href`.

So `anchor = "some url";`

So changing the value of a string variable will not change the href.

You can do this instead:

```
var anchor = document.getElementById('myAnchor').href;
anchor = "http://www.newgrounds.com";
document.getElementById('myAnchor').href = anchor;
```

The others worked because they were pointers but the last one was a string.

Comment: ah alright, thanks for clearing that up. i guess i better learn about pointers then

Answer (score 0):

In the last statement, `anchor` is an string, not an reference.

You are assigning a reference of `anchor` element

```
 var anchor = document.getElementById('myAnchor'); // Reference to anchor element
 anchor.href = "http://www.newgrounds.com";
```

You are getting a value of `href` element and assign to another variable.

```
 // Value of href element, not an reference
 var anchor = document.getElementById('myAnchor').href; 
 anchor = "http://www.newgrounds.com";
```